# Unsigned Int in JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

What can i do so JPA (i use Hibernate) creates Columns with Unsigned types? Currently all my ID columns are signed.

Comment: Unsigned SQL types, or Java types? Java does not have native unsigned number types. If you want to use an unsigned SQL type, you have to map it to a sufficiently-large (signed) Java type. For example, an unsigned 32-bit integer type would have to be stored in a (signed) Java `long`.

Comment: I want to use unsigned SQL types.

Comment: Then the answer is to map those to Java `long` fields.

Comment: i know, i'm looking for ways to have hibernate create the unsigned columns for me. By default hibernate maps my (signed) java long to a signed Bigint(20). I want to make the column unsigned int(11).

Comment: How are you configuring the mappings? XML or annotations? Are you using Hibernate to generate your schema?

Comment: I'm using jpa annotations. I want to avoid hibernate annotations if possible

Comment: my tables are created by my jpa provider (hibernate).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using the [`columnDefinition` property on the `@Column` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property-column) should do it. Taking a *total* guess at the SQL type you're going for:

```
private long foo;

@Column(columnDefinition = "UNSIGNED INT(11)")
public long getFoo()
{
    return foo;
}
```

**N.B.** Not all databases (like SQL Server, I think) support unsigned int types.

Comment: In MySQL the word "UNSIGNED" should come **after** "INT(11)".

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench "UNSIGNED" should come after "INT(11)"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has excellent documentation addressing the same problem. [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

If you are creating tables using DDLs (manually or using DB migration tools) and only want to understand which Java data type best suits your MySQL Unsigned Int column, the answer is `long`/`Long`.