# UNSIGNED constraint for INT(11) in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, tomcat

I have been trying to add constraint UNSIGNED to a column using MYSQL. Below is my table.

```
public class UserActivity implements BaseEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
Long id;

Long entityId;

@Column(columnDefinition = "enum('QUESTION','ANSWER', 'COMMENT', 'TAGS')")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Type type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, columnDefinition="INT(11) UNSIGNED")
CustomerEntity user;
```

But it is not creating that constraint for user column in the database due to which foreign key  and index are not setting up. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341084/how-can-a-javax-persistence-column-be-defined-as-an-unsigned-tinyint) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261094/unsigned-int-in-jpa-and-hibernate/5261992#5261992) could not help. Kindly help me out. Thanks

LOGS:

```
Hibernate:
alter table UserActivity
    add constraint FK_jfw954ii6gw7mbqdth6y3n0rs
    foreign key (user_Id)
    references customerDb.customer (Id)
12:31:30.350 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table UserActivity add constraint FK_jfw954ii6gw7mbqdth6y3n0rs foreign key (user_Id) references customerDb.customer (Id)
12:31:30.350 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Can't create table 'community_db.#sql-43f0_5a07' (errno: 150)
Hibernate:
```

MySQL Queries :

```
ALTER TABLE `community_db`.`Question` 
ADD INDEX `fk_Question_Customer_idx` (`author_Id` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `community_db`.`Question` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Answer_Customer`
FOREIGN KEY (`author_Id`)
REFERENCES `customerDb`.`customer` (`Id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

and below are the logs for the above mysql queries :

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'community_db.#sql-43f0_5d19' (errno: 150) 0.048 sec
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error you are getting?

Comment: In the logs I searched for 'UNSIGNED' but could not find. There are no queries for UNSIGNED and show_sql and format_sql is true

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I 've added the query from the log

Comment: `UNSIGNED INT(11)`

Comment: Could you also update with the exact MySQL `ALTER TABLE` statement which you would run on your own to add the constraint?  This might be useful to try to debug this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated!

Comment: The constraint queries do not seem to be matching.

Comment: Yup, where ever there is a many to one relation with customer this happens. Question also contains @manyToOne Customer

Comment: I think your Hibernate design is off, rather than the column being the issue.

Comment: I also feel that because there wasn't any query for UNSIGNED contraint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `columnDefinition` property value of the `@JoinColumn` or the foreign key must be equal to the `columnDefinition` property value of the `@Column` annotation present in the Entity Id, i.e., they must have the same property.

Below is the CustomerEntity

```
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="persistenceUnit")
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "customerDb")
public class CustomerEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT(11) UNSIGNED")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
..................
}
```

And in the UserActivity which would contain the customer Id as the foreign 
key the same same columndDefinition must be present.

```
public class UserActivity implements BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    Long entityId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "INT(11) UNSIGNED")
    CustomerEntity user;
..................
}
```

I created that table using IntelliJIdea which did not added those property due to which I got the error.